# Python: Get file path of the scripts which imports a module

Tags: python, file, import, module, path

I want to make a module and to find the path of the scripts which import my module. For example I have a module: *myscript.py* which is imported by *test.py*. I want to print from *myscript.py*, the path to *test.py* file

How can i do this? I have read about __ file __, but it doesn't really work the way i imagined it will work.

myscript.py

```
def printName():
    print __file__
```

test.py - i call this script

```
import myscript
myscript.printName()
```

I want to print **test.py** but it prints **myscript.py**

Comment: Why not use `print __file__` in test.py?

Comment: I need to know in the imported module the script which it calls

Answer (score 1):

```
import __main__

def printName():
    print __main__.__file__
```